# How can I run a function for 6 seconds at every minute (Python)?

Tags: python

My program needs to get some data from an API, but at a constant interval and for just 6 seconds at every 60 seconds. Running a while loop without stopping is too CPU intense, and I do not want that.

```
while loop:
    candles = get_candles(ACTIVE, TIMEFRAME, 6, time()) 
    # get data while the loop is running
....
```

All I need is to stop the loop for 60 seconds and run the loop from second 57 to second 3 at every 60 seconds. All the data I need is in this 6 seconds interval.

For example, from 14:00:57 to 14:01:03 I retrieve the data, and the rest of the time, the function waits.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import time

start = time.time()
while loop:
    check = time.time()
    candles = get_candles(ACTIVE, TIMEFRAME, 6, time())
    if check - start >= 6:
        time.sleep(54)
        start = time.time()
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `time.sleep(60 - (check - start))`. If the get_candles() function runs for too long, you want to reduce the sleep time by the corresponding amount.

Comment: This is still running as many times as possible for 6 seconds. This answers what OP wants, but OP probably wants the wrong thing.